# Android SQLite connection management

Tags: android, database, sqlite, connection

I'm working with SQLite in my android project. There is a feature that is clear to me -- if there are multiple threads working with DB then they should use only ONE instance of DBHelper and SQLite guarantee a safe access (even if it is concurrent) to the DB. 
But I still have one thing needed to be clarified. How should I manage with DB connection (`SQLiteDatabase` object)? How often should I call `geWritableDatabase()` and `close()`? Is it ok if I call these methods once? Or it's better to obtain SQLDatabase object and close one every time I perform read/write operation on DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is handled by default... I mean if a writtable database open, whenever you try to access read-only database it closes writtable one and create new read-only database instance. As far as i know :)

Comment: And if I want to write into DB from multiple threads than should getWritableDatabase() and close() be invoked in each of them?

Comment: Yes. it is better to invoke getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase() methods every time just to be sure which one you are about to use... Also if there is a multi-threading you have to manage some kind of synchronization there, where no developer wants his/her database closed while fetching data from database

Comment: Also take a look javadoc description...Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object will be returned in the future.

Comment: As a matter of fact, `getReadableDatabase` returns write-able connection in most cases. You only get read-only connection if device is running out of memory.